# urllib3 - Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]

Tags: python, python-requests, openstack, urllib3

I am working in the code modifications on my local setup of openstack Designate.

Actually it was working fine before.

But now I am trying to execute the same command which was working fine before.

Unfortunately now for the same command, I am getting an error which is as follows:

```
root@newds:~# designate record-list 5e18999d-1b4c-43f9-94e8-2bb2aab46aa0
ERROR: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9001): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1//domains/5e18999d-1b4c-43f9-94e8-2bb2aab46aa0/records (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2077e2c210>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Some one help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution myself.

Actually it was an error with the packages which was corrupted.

I re-installed the same.

So that I can be able to see that it was back to working state as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solved case for you to reference.
I found the same problem when i want to run the command `watcher audit list` (watcher is a optimization component in Openstack and `watcher audit list` is to list all the audits already defined in watcher).

After checking the running progress using `ps aux |grep watcher`, I found that the watcher service is not running at all.

So I restart the necessary watcher-api and watcher-decision-engine progress using

```
python /usr/local/bin/watcher-api --config-file /etc/watcher/watcher.conf &
```

and

```
python /usr/local/bin/watcher-decision-engine --config-file /etc/watcher/watcher.conf &
```

Then the problem is solved and the command `watcher audit list` works again!!